# Explode json in Hive

Tags: json, facebook, dictionary, hive

I have a json stored in hive which looks like:

```
{"SHAREit":"4666179584","Google Play Store":"515161408","Internet":"369566560","Facebook":"257369824","YouTube":"173979008"}
```

I would like to have this json stored in another table in the following way:

```
|SHAREit           |           4666179584|
|------------------+---------------------+
|Google Play       |           515161408 |
|------------------+---------------------+
|Internet          |           369566560 |
|------------------+---------------------+
|Facebook          |           257369824 |
|------------------+---------------------+
|YouTube           |           173979008 |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried to follow the tutorial from the link https://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/ but I am getting the following error:

`FAILED: SemanticException 1:164 AS clause has an invalid number of aliases. Error encountered near token 'usage'`

My query:

```
select  apps,usage from my_table 
LATERAL VIEW explode_map(json_map(app_bytes,'string, string')) appsTable as apps,usage 
where appsTable.day='2016-06-11' and appsTable.event_info.type="TRACK_APP_BYTES";
```

PS: app_bytes is the name of the column in my_table

Comment: have a look at this http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

The example you mentioned uses UDFs like json_map that are NOT STANDARD HIVE. You have to build and load the brickhouse code from [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse), compile and install them on your machine to use them.

I think the easiest way is to use json_tuple, since your case is fairly straightforward (no nested structures, etc). Something like the following will extract the fields you need, which you can then store in a table.

```
select  x.* from my_table                    
  LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(app_bytes,'SHAREit',
    'Google Play Store','Internet','Facebook','YouTube') x  ;
```